# PHP thumbnail with white background and not centralized

Tags: php, background, center, thumbnails, gd

I have the following php script to create thumbnail after uploading an image. It is working properly, but it creates a black background and does not center the image if it is not the size you want, does anyone know how to leave the white background and center it?

How to fix it
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYYfI.jpg

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
{
$filetmp = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
$filename = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
$filetype = $_FILES["image"]["type"];
$filesize = $_FILES["image"]["size"];
$fileinfo = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
$filewidth = $fileinfo[0];
$fileheight = $fileinfo[1];
$filepath = "../uploads/";
$filepath_thumb = "../thumbnail/";

if($filetmp == "")
{
    echo "please select a photo";
}
else
{

    if($filesize > 2097152)
    {
        echo "photo > 2mb";
    }
    else
    {

        if($filetype != "image/jpeg" && $filetype != "image/png" && $filetype != "image/gif")
        {
            echo "Please upload jpg / png / gif";
        }
        else
        {
            $final_image = rand(1000,1000000).$filename;
            $filepath = $filepath.strtolower($final_image);
            move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filepath);             

            if($filetype == "image/jpeg")
            {
              $imagecreate = "imagecreatefromjpeg";
              $imageformat = "imagejpeg";
            }
            if($filetype == "image/png")
            {                        
              $imagecreate = "imagecreatefrompng";
              $imageformat = "imagepng";
            }
            if($filetype == "image/gif")
            {                        
              $imagecreate= "imagecreatefromgif";
              $imageformat = "imagegif";
            }

            $new_width = "200";
            $new_height = "200";


            $filepath_thumb = $filepath_thumb.strtolower($final_image);
            $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
            $image = $imagecreate($filepath); //photo folder
            if($filewidth > $fileheight) 
            {
                $thumb_w    =   $new_width;
                $thumb_h    =   $fileheight*($new_height/$filewidth);
            }

            if($filewidth < $fileheight) 
            {
                $thumb_w    =   $filewidth*($new_width/$fileheight);
                $thumb_h    =   $new_height;
            }

            if($filewidth == $fileheight) 
            {
                $thumb_w    =   $new_width;
                $thumb_h    =   $new_height;
            }

            $dst_img        =   ImageCreateTrueColor($thumb_w,$thumb_h);

            imagecopyresampled($image_p,$image,0,0,0,0,$thumb_w,$thumb_h,$filewidth,$fileheight);

            $imageformat($image_p, $filepath_thumb);//thumb folder      



        }

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Black is the default background, you just have to set the background colour of the new image to white first.

```
//set background colour white before copying
$white = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($image_p, 0, 0, $white);

imagecopyresampled($image_p,$image,0,0,0,0,$thumb_w,$thumb_h,$filewidth,$fileheight);

$imageformat($image_p, $filepath_thumb);//thumb folder
```

Also, $dst_img doesn't appear to be used.

Centering (untested, but simple enough math):

```
$xOffset = (imagesx($p_image)-$thumb_w) / 2;
$yOffset = (imagesy($p_image)-$thumb_h) / 2;

imagecopyresampled($image_p,$image,$offsetX,$offsetY,0,0,$thumb_w,$thumb_h,$filewidth,$fileheight);
```

If you know which dimension does not match the new thumbnail dimension this could be simplified.

Comment: Thank you very much the background has gone white, but how can I centralize the image?

Comment: Centering the image is pretty simple math. $xOffset = (imagesx($image)-imagesx($p_image)) / 2; $yOffset = (imagesy($image)-imagesy($p_image)) / 2; and set the destination x,y that are currently 0,0 to the offsets in imagecopyresampled. (I'll update the post too)

Comment: I used your code, but two problems occurred.
I put $ xOffset inside if ($ filewidth <$ fileheight) and $ yOffset inside if ($ filewidth> $ fileheight), since it was the only way to work something, but when it occurs if ($ filewidth <$ fileheight) image cuts as at https://imgur.com/a/KxfpKC7 and stays on the right side. Already when I use if ($ filewidth> $ fileheight) everything goes white!

Comment: It's hard for me to guess what's wrong if you didn't use the code as posted. Please update your original or add an edited version.

Comment: I think I misinterpreted the size of $image, try the edited version diffing the thumbnail and thumbnail image content instead of the 2 images.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was such a simple error to understand I was a stupid, thank you very much! : D